# Add new row to a table by clicking the icon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a table which include a "+" font awesome icon.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<table class="table table-bordered w-auto">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column_1</th>
      <th>Column_2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="form-group" style="position: relative">
        <input type="Column_1" class="form-control" id="clmn1" placeholder="Enter the name">
        <div class="justify-content-center" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; left: 50%;">
            <a class="fa fa-plus-circle" href="#"></a>
          </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now how to add a new row by clicking on the "+" icon?

Comment: can you please put your code in snippet

Comment: @Harshsetia I put it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add another row without using javascript or Jquery. here is a solution:-

```js
function addrow(){
  var row =     "<tr><td class='form-group' style='position: relative'><input type='Column_1' class='form-control' id='clmn1' placeholder='Enter the name'><div class='justify-content-center' style='position: absolute; width: 100%; left: 50%;'></div></td></tr>";


  document.getElementById("myList").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', row);


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    

  </head>
  
  <body>


<table class="table table-bordered w-auto">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column_1</th>
      <th>Column_2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myList">
    <tr >
      <td class="form-group" style="position: relative">
        <input type="Column_1" class="form-control" id="clmn1" placeholder="Enter the name">
    
      </td>
    </tr>

   
  </tbody>
  <tfoot> <tr><td><a onclick="addrow()" class="fa fa-plus-circle" href="#"></a></tfoot></td></tr>
  
    

</table>



  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Harshetia, can you please do a bit more, I need the plus sign to be always on the last row.

Comment: @Ismail86 I have change the snippet . please check